# Change file Permissions on Windows Server Host

Tags: windows-server

I uploaded my site to my host, everything is ok except for mdb file write problem. I'm using it as my database but access file is read-only by default. How can I set its file permissions? I tried changing it with filezilla but it works only on linux servers. Can anyone help?

Regards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the hosting companies provide a control panel like websitepanel, plesk or helm to change / modify permission of your files.

If you can share the control panel name you're using, we can give you step by step instructions for changing file permission.